# does win8 app store accept app developed by c++

Tags: c#, javascript, c++, windows, windows-runtime

Does Win8 App Store accept application written in c++?
I develop wp7 app using c#, and plan to develop app for win8 metro app.
Just wonder if win8 app store accept app using c++ or only accpet app develop by c# and javascript

I welcome any comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Windows 8 store will accept any valid metro applications, including those written in the languages Microsoft provides code examples for!

There are plenty of helpful resources to get you started, on [MSDN Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/TechEd/Europe/2012/DEV367) (this link confirming that the Windows 8 store accepts C++ applications), as well as the full documentation for [Metro-style applications in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh700360).